# designing cascading style sheet(css)

Tags: css

coding to get rounded corners for text box using cascading style sheet(css)

Comment: Tempted to edit it, but first let me know do you mean textbox as in `<textarea>` or an element with text in it?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

If you want to be picky, you can go back to the old four divisions, each with a different corner to the box specified in the background.

CSS:

```
div.box { background: url(top-left.png) top left no-repeat }
div.box div { background: url(top-right.png) top right no-repeat }
div.box div div { background: url(bottom-right.png) bottom right no-repeat }
div.box div div div { background: url(bottom-left.png) bottom left no-repeat }
div.box div div div div { background: none } // So extra divisions don't add another corner
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"><div><div><div>
Some text, blah blah blah
</div></div></div></div>
```

I actually use this method for my website, and then use the border-radius for unimportant things like input fields and small little boxes here and there.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that CSS sprites would be much better for this (and perfectly suited).

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type='text']
{
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

You can also try this http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Generate anything you want: http://css3please.com/